# Early return from within a fold

Tags: rust, fold

I've been trying to lean more into Rust's functional language features so I'm trying to take this function:

1. ```rust
   fn minimum_length(s: String) -> i32 {
       if s.len() <= 1 {
           return s.len() as i32;
       }

       let mut len_after_deleting_similar_ends = s.len();
       let x = len_after_deleting_similar_ends / 2;

       for (first_char, last_char) in zip(s.chars().take(x), s.chars().rev().take(x)) {
           if first_char == last_char {
               len_after_deleting_similar_ends -= 2
           } else {
               return len_after_deleting_similar_ends as i32
           }
       };

       len_after_deleting_similar_ends as i32
   }
   ```

and rewrite it to use the `fold` method instead of a loop, currently my code is:

2. ```rust
   fn minimum_length_fold(s: String) -> i32 {
       if s.len() <= 1 {
           return s.len() as i32;
       }

       let len_after_deleting_similar_ends = zip(s.chars().take(s.len() / 2), s.chars().rev().take(s.len() / 2))
           .fold(s.len(), |acc, (first_char, last_char)| {
               println!("{first_char} {last_char} {acc}");
               if first_char == last_char {
                   acc - 2
               } else {
                   return acc;
               }
        });

       len_after_deleting_similar_ends as i32
   }
   ```

However, any case that would cause an early return in the first function (except for an early return on the final pair of letters) will give an incorrect result. This is because the `return` returns to the `fold` rather than returning to the caller of `minimum_length_fold` and therefore the functionality is the same as if `return` was omitted.

How can I change this so that a mismatching pair of letters results in an early return or some similarly efficient solution?

My tests are:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_1() {
        assert_eq!(minimum_length(String::from("ca")), 2)
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_2() {
        assert_eq!(minimum_length(String::from("cabaabac")), 0);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_3() {
        assert_eq!(minimum_length(String::from("caaaabac")), 4);
    }
}
```

`minimum_length` will pass all three whereas `minimum_length_fold` will fail `test_3` on account of it not returning early and the accumulator has currently been reduced due to the matching `'a'` at index 3 and index 4, it passes `test_2` despite the lack of an early return as there are no subsequent matching pairs of letters which would cause the accumulator to be reduced and therefore the answer is correct despite the flawed logic.

Comment: Use `try_fold` for early returns. But honestly `fold` is just unidiomatic here.

Comment: @cafce25 thanks, what would be idiomatic in this situation

Comment: Your first solution.

Comment: Or you could `.take_while()` before you `fold` ?

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing what is actually asked for is how to do this using iterators. Here is a way without using fold (using count instead):

```rust
fn minimum_length(s: &str) -> usize {
    s.len() - 2 * s.chars().zip(s.chars().rev()).take_while(|(a,b)|a==b).take(s.len()/2).count()
}
```

This is probably as fast as the first solution.

One thing to consider is how to handle for example "a". As you have written the function, it should return 1, but both sides of the string are the same, so maybe the 'a' should be removed, and the function return 0.

Comment: Thanks, this was initially from a leetcode problem I which I slightly misunderstood (the problem was able to take any number of characters from the front and end provided the first pair matched rather than just the first pair e.g. it could take "aaaba" -> "b" as the first and last character matched and it is then allowed to take as many "a"'s from the front as it can. My intention was for an iterator based approach as they tend to be easy to work with drastically reduce memory management headaches and be very fast but I was also interested in the fold specifically. Great name btw